# Populate local text file data to web page using html

Tags: javascript, html

> I have a file name code.txt and I wanted to populate the data from the code.txt file. I wrote some code by searching on the internet but it is not working. The console.log(text) does not print anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = fs.readFileSync("C:/code.txt").toString('utf-8');
    console.log(text);
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fs.readFileSync - it's NodeJS module (server side), not browser side JS

Comment: You ***cannot*** access local files like that from the browser. Then any malicious site could easily read any of your files.

Comment: You would have to upload code.txt online and fetch it from your site. That would probably be the simplest way.

Comment: Alternatively if your code.txt contains js code, all you have to do is rename it to code.js, and  include this in your code: `<script src="code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and your js code will run when you access the page.

Comment: Do note that `code.txt` has to be in the same directory as your HTML file or you'll have to change the path accordingly for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have it done with AJAX request, like this:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
window.load = loadDoc();
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "text.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

> Note: You may run your test with a webserver (I tested this with XAMPP). Make sure your text file lives on same directory as your html file.